# Retrieve src data from jsp through form submit

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets, base64

In my jsp:

```
<form name="frmTest" action="test" method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="sub" name="sub" />
  <img id="cImg" name="cImg" src="${param.src}">
</form>
```

In my servlet:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws ServletException, IOException{

String imgUrl = req.getParameter("cImg");
```

I want to retrieve the **src** data of my image in canvas. It will be in base 64 data URI format. The above will give me null value. How should I go about doing it, any helps will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot, You can get data with only `name`  `attribute`.

What you can do is take a hidden variable ,add `value` to it and get in servlet.

Like

```
<form name="frmTest" action="test" method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="sub" name="sub" />
  <img id="cImg" name="cImg" src="${param.src}">
  <input type="hidden" name="hiddenSrc" value="${param.src}" />
</form>
```

in servlet

```
String hiddenimgUrl = req.getParameter("hiddenSrc");
```

Comment: Oh, but I cannot use `${param.src}` as the value. Mainly because it is the original url of the image. I have performed image manipulation in html5 canvas and reassigned the src to cImg. `document.getElementById('cImg').src = dataURL;`

Comment: @Sky Then update the hidden variable too. `document.getElementById('hiddenvarId').value= dataURL;`   :)

Comment: Hey, I must be tired. I was like going in a round when the solution is simple. You really helped a tired man like me, thanks and have a great day!

Comment: @Sky Glad to help you :) Good day too.